# Why do Dharmafarer URL links to Piya Tan's publications not work anymore?

Tags: support, feature-request, status-completed

For example, in [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/25945/471), the Dharmafarer URL does not work anymore (as of today):

http://dharmafarer.org/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/14.13-Khemaka-S-s22.89-piya.pdf

How can we fix it?

Comment: You might accept [Catija's answer](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2283/254) if your testing shows you that the URLs are working correctly again now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to some work by [Shog9](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/users/3/shog9?tab=profile), all 466 of these links [have been updated](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=activity&sort=revisions) for you, so even if the dharmafarer site doesn't update their links, you won't need to worry about editing them all manually.

He used the suggested replacement ruben2020 mentioned, so hopefully there shouldn't be any problems. If there are, please let us know and we'll try to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

To fix the Dharmafarer URLs, change from:

http://dharmafarer.org/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/14.13-Khemaka-S-s22.89-piya.pdf

To:

http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/14.13-Khemaka-S-s22.89-piya.pdf

This means that `dharmafarer.org/wordpress` must be changed to `www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer`

I'm not sure if the moderators have some special admin tools to change this automatically throughout Buddhism.SE. If there isn't such a tool, then this would be a good feature request for StackExchange.

Answer (score 1):

I asked about that a couple of weeks ago ...

[How to find and/or change a set of hyperlinks on a site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313243/139866)

... this has happened before but there isn't such a tool.

It's easy to find all the links (with an already-existing query -- i.e. there are about 460 posts affected), but the edits must be done manually (because there's no existing tool), or someone needs to write a tool to do the edits semi-automatically (using the Stack Exchange API), or someone needs to ask one of the Stack Exchange developers to do it.

I also wrote to The Minding Centre (also on July 27), to tell them of the problem and suggest they fix this at their end (by supporting their old URLs, by implementing redirection) -- someone there wrote back, saying they had forwarded my email to their technical volunteer, but nothing after that.

---

To test whether [they're fixed now](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2283/254) look at some of the 400+ hyperlinks which now start with `www.themindingcentre.org` e.g. found by this query:

https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3Athemindingcentre.org

I haven't tested them all, but the first and last ones on the list seem to work now, so, thank you.